# mySQL really slow running query - 60 seconds

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, query-optimization, database-indexes

I have a query on Drupal 7 that's taking upwards of 60 seconds to run. There's a number of joins, but all items that are being joined on have indexes (BTREE) so I'm not sure why they are running so slowly. Maybe this is just the way it is? I'm not a DBA, or the developer of this query, but I am trying to diagnose the bottle neck, as we're seeing big problems when, for instance, Google indexes us.

Thank you for any help you provide.

*** UPDATED QUERY and EXPLAIN** 
 **Note, that after making the changes recommended I was able to at least get the processing time down by about 20%. It's still slow, but getting quicker. There are indexes on all fields in the where and order by clauses. Also, I'm not sure how I'd be able to stop using "!=" and not in. I'd certainly be open to suggestions. Finally, I'm also unsure how to get it to stop using filesort or to respect my indexes. I'm happy to publish the indexes if you think it will help :) Thanks everyone for your help so far! ***

```
   SELECT 
    n.type AS type,
    CASE
        WHEN n.type = 'book_new' THEN workid.field_workid_target_id
        ELSE n.nid
    END AS uuid,
    CASE
        WHEN n.type = 'book_new' THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(sale_date.field_onsaledate_value))
        ELSE n.created
    END AS sort_date
FROM
    node n
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_related_books books ON n.nid = books.entity_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_author_ref author_refs ON books.entity_id = author_refs.entity_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_workid workid ON n.nid = workid.entity_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_onsaledate sale_date ON workid.entity_id = sale_date.entity_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_format format ON sale_date.entity_id = format.entity_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_subjectcategories subjects ON format.entity_id = subjects.entity_id
        AND subjects.field_subjectcategories_tid = '48981'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_subjectcategories subjects2 ON subjects.entity_id = subjects2.entity_id
        AND subjects2.field_subjectcategories_tid = '54556'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_subjectcategories subjects3 ON subjects2.entity_id = subjects3.entity_id
        AND subjects3.field_subjectcategories_tid = '61091'
WHERE
    ((books.field_related_books_target_id IN ('874271'))
        OR (author_refs.field_author_ref_target_id IN ('874561' , '572716', '874551'))
        OR (((subjects.field_subjectcategories_tid IS NOT NULL)
        AND (subjects2.field_subjectcategories_tid IS NOT NULL))
        OR ((subjects2.field_subjectcategories_tid IS NOT NULL)
        AND (subjects3.field_subjectcategories_tid IS NOT NULL))
        OR ((subjects.field_subjectcategories_tid IS NOT NULL)
        AND (subjects3.field_subjectcategories_tid IS NOT NULL))))
        AND (n.status = '1')
        AND (n.type != 'wow')
        AND (n.type != 'event')
        AND (n.type != 'slice')
        AND (n.nid NOT IN ('874271'))
        AND (sale_date.field_onsaledate_value < CURDATE()
        OR sale_date.field_onsaledate_value IS NULL)
        AND ((format.field_format_tid NOT IN ('2296' , '4986', '1641', '1756'))
        OR (format.field_format_tid IS NULL))

GROUP BY uuid

ORDER BY    books.field_related_books_target_id = 874271 DESC , 
            author_refs.field_author_ref_target_id = 874561 DESC , 
            author_refs.field_author_ref_target_id = 572716 DESC , 
            author_refs.field_author_ref_target_id = 874551 DESC , 
            sort_date DESC
LIMIT 36 OFFSET 35;



   +----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------------------------------+------------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys                         | key              | key_len | ref                       | rows   | filtered | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------------------------------+------------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | n           | ref  | PRIMARY,node_status_type,node_type    | node_status_type | 4       | const                     | 342627 |      100 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | books       | ref  | entity_id                             | entity_id        | 4       | prhc2.n.nid               |      1 |      100 | NULL                                                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | author_refs | ref  | entity_id                             | entity_id        | 4       | prhc2.books.entity_id     |      1 |      100 | NULL                                                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | workid      | ref  | entity_id                             | entity_id        | 4       | prhc2.n.nid               |      1 |      100 | NULL                                                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sale_date   | ref  | entity_id                             | entity_id        | 4       | prhc2.workid.entity_id    |      1 |      100 | Using where                                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | format      | ref  | entity_id                             | entity_id        | 4       | prhc2.sale_date.entity_id |      1 |      100 | Using where                                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | subjects    | ref  | entity_id,field_subjectcategories_tid | entity_id        | 4       | prhc2.format.entity_id    |      1 |      100 | Using where                                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | subjects2   | ref  | entity_id,field_subjectcategories_tid | entity_id        | 4       | prhc2.subjects.entity_id  |      1 |      100 | Using where                                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | subjects3   | ref  | entity_id,field_subjectcategories_tid | entity_id        | 4       | prhc2.subjects2.entity_id |      1 |      100 | Using where                                            |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------------------------------+------------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+



describe node;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| nid       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| vid       | int(10) unsigned | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| type      | varchar(32)      | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| language  | varchar(12)      | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| title     | varchar(255)     | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| uid       | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| status    | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 1       |                |
| created   | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| changed   | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| comment   | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| promote   | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| sticky    | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| tnid      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| translate | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| downgrade | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

describe field_data_field_related_books;
+-------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entity_type                   | varchar(128)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| bundle                        | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted                       | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id                     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id                   | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| language                      | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta                         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field_related_books_target_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

describe field_data_field_author_ref;
+----------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entity_type                | varchar(128)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| bundle                     | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted                    | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id                  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id                | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| language                   | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta                      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field_author_ref_target_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

describe field_data_field_workid;
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entity_type            | varchar(128)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| bundle                 | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted                | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id            | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| language               | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta                  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field_workid_target_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

describe field_data_field_onsaledate;
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entity_type            | varchar(128)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| bundle                 | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted                | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id            | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| language               | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta                  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field_onsaledate_value | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

describe field_data_field_format;
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entity_type      | varchar(128)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| bundle           | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted          | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id      | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| language         | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field_format_tid | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

describe field_data_field_subjectcategories;
+-----------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entity_type                 | varchar(128)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| bundle                      | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted                     | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id                   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id                 | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| language                    | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta                       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field_subjectcategories_tid | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: run `explain your_query_here` to see mysql's execution plan, including whatever indexes it decided to use.

Comment: Marc B, I did. It's just below the query above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to the order of the joins, i'm not sure if that has anything to do with the slowness, but when joining multiple tables I try to chain them in a logical way starting from the first table and moving to the next, next, next, ... I don't jump back to the same table from an earlier join unless it was a self-join and I aliased it. It will help you keep track of your joins a little better if you had them better organized, here it is:

```
    SELECT 
    n.type AS type,
    CASE
        WHEN n.type = 'book_new' THEN workid.field_workid_target_id
        ELSE n.nid
    END AS uuid,
    CASE
        WHEN n.type = 'book_new' THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(sale_date.field_onsaledate_value))
        ELSE n.created
    END AS sort_date
FROM
    node n
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_related_books books ON n.nid = books.entity_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_author_ref author_refs ON books.entity_id = author_refs.entity_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_workid workid ON workid.nid = author_refs.entity_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_onsaledate sale_date ON workid.entity_id = sale_date.entity_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_format format ON sale_date.entity_id = format.entity_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_subjectcategories subjects ON format.entity_id = subjects.entity_id
        AND subjects.field_subjectcategories_tid = '48981'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_subjectcategories subjects2 ON subjects.entity_id = subjects2.entity_id
        AND subjects2.field_subjectcategories_tid = '54556'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    field_data_field_subjectcategories subjects3 ON subjects2.entity_id = subjects3.entity_id
        AND subjects3.field_subjectcategories_tid = '61091'
WHERE
    ((books.field_related_books_target_id IN ('874271'))
        OR (author_refs.field_author_ref_target_id IN ('874561' , '572716', '874551'))
        OR (((subjects.field_subjectcategories_tid IS NOT NULL)
        AND (subjects2.field_subjectcategories_tid IS NOT NULL))
        OR ((subjects2.field_subjectcategories_tid IS NOT NULL)
        AND (subjects3.field_subjectcategories_tid IS NOT NULL))
        OR ((subjects.field_subjectcategories_tid IS NOT NULL)
        AND (subjects3.field_subjectcategories_tid IS NOT NULL))))
        AND (n.status = '1')
        AND (n.nid NOT IN ('874271'))
        AND (n.type != 'wow')
        AND (n.type != 'event')
        AND (n.type != 'slice')
        AND (sale_date.field_onsaledate_value < CURDATE()
        OR sale_date.field_onsaledate_value IS NULL)
        AND ((format.field_format_tid NOT IN ('2296' , '4986', '1641', '1756'))
        OR (format.field_format_tid IS NULL))
GROUP BY uuid
ORDER BY books.field_related_books_target_id = 874271 DESC , author_refs.field_author_ref_target_id = 874561 DESC , author_refs.field_author_ref_target_id = 572716 DESC , author_refs.field_author_ref_target_id = 874551 DESC , sort_date DESC
LIMIT 36 OFFSET 35;
```

The other thing that I would check is the indexes you have on the table. All those where conditions should be indexed. Indexes are another thing that have to be done right, you don't want to over do it and you want it to be logical, the order will make a difference.

I noticed in the Explain query that you had 342627, is this the total records you have in the database? If it is, that means that it's doing a full table scan and not respecting the indexes, which i only seen 2 "condition" and "temporary".

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions Hatem. I'm going to try now.

Comment: I just noticed your question, sorry Hatem. 342627 is the number of records in the node table.

Comment: Hi Hatem. I was just following up to see if you had any additional insights.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, your indexes are not being hit due to the structure of the where conditions, a few comments;

- NOT IN is terribly inefficient, consider changing this to something else
- "Using index condition" on the node table, indicates that there where clause does not contain something useful enough to use indexes and has choses to do a full table scan. I can see that you have n.type indexed, consider indexing n.nid of not already and use another operator other not !=
- Your order by is causing a file sort, look at your mysql configuration and ensure it's been optimised for file sorts; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Thank you for your response harvey. I'm going through and checking the indexes on the where clauses now.

Comment: It looks like every column has an index. I'm not sure where else to go.